# How to make an asynchronous cast iron database call?

Tags: asynchronous, call

Is there a way to ensure that an asynchronous cast iron call can be made to two databases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to do, especially in the case where you want to call SAP and another DB at the same time. SAP along does not allow for asynchronous calls.